# How much energy can be produced by burning sewage gas?

Tags: energy, combustion, hydrocarbons

I am an eighth grader. I need to make a science project on the production of electricity from sewage. I know that almost sixty percent of sewage gas is Methane and most of the other constituents are combustible. I wanted to know how much energy can be produced by combustion of sewage gas and what amount of it can be converted to mechanical and thermal energy and how much of it is lost.

I was thinking of burning the gas to heat water to steam which in turn would turn the blades of a turbine, which would generate the electricity. I don't know exactly how that would work and how efficient that would be, but I am working on it.

Comment: First of all, welcome to SE.Chemistry!  Your question is excellent and demonstrates that you have taken some time to learn about your topic (which is obviously a very important issue for our growing world).  Do you know how combustion of the gas or the sewage itself would be converted to mechanical or thermal energy and why some of it would be lost?  If you had some idea of these things, this would be an excellent addition to your question.  If you can learn these things, or take your best guess, I think you should edit your question to include those things.  Again, good job and good luck!

Comment: You need to decide by what kind of machine you want to burn the sewage gas, and then check the technical specifications. The absolute heating value of methane should also be simple to find.

Comment: @airhuff, I have edited the question to include what I was thinking. I know that some of the energy would be lost because of the second law of thermodynamics, and that's about as much as I understood about that.